# How do I build a regex to match these `long` values?

Tags: java, regex

How do I build a regular expression for a long data type in Java, I currently have a regex expression for 3 double values as my pattern:

```
String pattern = "(max=[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*) *(total=[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*) *(free=[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*)";
```

I am constructing the pattern using the line:

```
Pattern a = Pattern.compile("control.avgo:", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

I want to match the numbers following the equals signs in the example text below, from the file `control.avgo`.

```
max=259522560, total=39325696, free=17979640
```

What do I need to do to correct my code to match them?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your text. Can you clearly show a sample input, and make it clear what you want to output?

Comment: Ok the third line is an output to a txt file the regex initially finds the control.avgo: line and then regex's the remainder of the line in order to extract the variables. Put my pattern doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @HopelessProgrammer Could it be that you only need to extract the double values from any text?

Comment: Why not just `split` on `','` and then split each resulting element on `'='`?

Comment: Many thanks to all responders shall upvote everyone as it is all feasible just had to pick one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to address several errors, including:

- Your pattern specifies real numbers, but your question asks for long integers.
- Your pattern omits the commas in the string being searched.
- The first argument to Pattern.compile() is the regular expression, not the string being searched.

This will work:

```
    String sPattern = "max=([0-9]+), total=([0-9]+), free=([0-9]+)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( sPattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE );

    String source = "control.avgo: max=259522560, total=39325696, free=17979640";
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( source );
    if ( matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("max=" + matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println("total=" + matcher.group(2));
        System.out.println("free=" + matcher.group(3));
    }
```

If you want to convert the numbers you find to a numeric type, use `Long.valueOf( String )`.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be that you actually need

```
Pattern a = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

instead of

```
Pattern a = Pattern.compile("control.avgo:", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

because your current code uses `"control.avgo:"` as the regex, and not the `pattern` you have defined.

Comment: Ok I'll implement that now to test.

Answer (score 2):

In case you only need to find any numerical preceded by "="...

```
String test = "3.control.avgo: max=259522560, total=39325696, free=17979640";
// looks for the "=" sign preceding any numerical sequence of any length
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\=)\\d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
// keeps on searching until cannot find anymore
while (matcher.find()) {
    // prints out whatever found
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Output:

```
259522560
39325696
17979640
```